# ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError when calculating Total of subtotals

Tags: angular

Been looking at several blogs and SO questions. In my template I have:

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of invoice_items; let x=index">
    <td>{{x+1}}</td>
    <td>{{item.name}}</td>
    <td>{{item.quantity}}</td>
    <td>{{item.unitprice}}</td>
    <td>{{subTotal(item.quantity,item.unitprice)}}</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>Total</td><td>{{total}}</td>
</tr>
```

In my component:

```
let total:number=0;

subTotal(q:number,p:number){
    let subtotal:number=q * p;

    this.total=this.total + subtotal;
    return subtotal;
}
```

Now I am getting the above error when it prints out {{total}}. My current solution is to calculate the total in the component itself by looping. But it means looping twice (in the component and the html).

Comment: Why not compute the total on component side, and have `subTotal` only do what it says, i.e. calculate and return the subtotal? Calling component methods with side effects from your template is considered bad practice.

Comment: yeah because your subTotal method mutates the state of the component instance...

Comment: @Jeto you mean loop the result in component to calculate the total? That works, indeed, but was thinking if there is a way to loop the items only once in the template, adding the total value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should compute the overall total on component side, for instance using [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```
this.total = this.invoice_items
  .reduce((total, item) => total + item.quantity * item.unitprice, 0);
```

Then on template side, replace:

```
{{subTotal(item.quantity,item.unitprice)}}
```

with simply:

```
{{item.quantity * item.unitprice}}
```

Comment: Thanks @Jeto. I had a similar solution; guess was hoping to loop only once. But yes, your .reduce solution is more elegant.